# Qt and Android - How to launch camera by using Qandroidjniobject

Tags: android, c++, qt, camera, qandroidjniobject

I am new in Qt android app development. I want to open camera and take picture and get the path of image by using QtAndroid, and JNIObject.

For example,

```
Intent capture_image_intent = new Intent();
capture_image_intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(capture_image_intent, 101);
```

I want to launch camera in my Qt android app by using Qandroidjniobject. So, please help me to write a code in qt.

Comment: Your intent will only give you a thumbnail as bitmap from the camera. Instead you should supply an uri with the intent where the camera can write the picture to. Then you know the uri already.

Comment: @blackapps, You are right, but I want to open camera by using intent in qandroidjniobject and take a captured image path.

Comment: With the intent you have now you will never get an uri or path. Change it as said before.

Comment: @blackapps, ok I will chenging my question

Comment: Your java code is already not suitable. So first post the right java code and then ask to translate it to your needs.

Comment: @blackapps, Ok thanks

Comment: @blackapps, Ok , Can you help me to correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this above problem in Qt by using Qandroidjniobject.

For launching camera by using intent code is given below,

```
QAndroidJniObject ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 
   QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/MediaStore", 
   "ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", 
    ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.object<jstring>());
QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.object<jobject>(), 101, this);
```

Comment: Nice. But do you get an uri for the picture taken?

Comment: @blackapps, Yes, and Thank you for asking.

Comment: How do you get the URI for the picture? The handleActivityResult callback has the QAndroidJniObject argument, but I don't know how to use it to get the image